# How to cap the amount of local storage for Photos App

Tags: icloud, photos, mojave, storage

Mojave and others have a feature where Photos is optimised for local storage, once triggered it will purge a certain amount of space by leaving low fidelity version of certain photos locally and the rest on iCloud.

However this only happens once the local disk is X% full (80%?).

Is there a workaround to cap the amount of storage available for the Photos app, so that is process is not taking over excessive amount of storage.

Cheers.

**Edit:**

- SSD Capacity `512 GB`
- Current Photos Cache: `150 GB`
- Photos to be Imported: `~1 TB`
- iCloud Storage Available: `~1.5 TB`

Comment: What is your ssd size and cloud photos library size and size of cached local content? I’ve never found the automatic behaviors maybe your case is different specifically.

Comment: SSD 512Gb, 
Photos ~1Tb, 
iCloud Storage Available ~1.5Tb

Comment: You could create a partition on you hard drive and use it for photos only. Set partition to 100 MB, for example, and you won't be able to exceed that.  Downside is you might lose the photos if you try to expand space by recreating a larger petition.

Comment: @jmh - thanks that's a good idea. I didn't understand your last statement though - 'you might lose the photos if you try to expand space by recreating a larger partition'. What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how the partition function works. it may ease the current partition if you try to expand it.  I don't know that it doesn't do that.  So I'd find out before you do it unless all photos are backed up.